# Amazon Product Advertising API using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-product-api

I am building an application that promotes amazon products...  Now, i am displaying 30 products in a page. how can i display 30 different product everyday (1-30 products Monday, 31-61 products Tuesday, so on..). I am using Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.2, amazon-ecs gem.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the week-day number-1 with 30 and you will get the offset for the day.

e.g. for Monday,
30x0 = offset is 0  => display records from 0-30

Tuesday
30x1 = offset is 30  => display records from 31-60

Wednesday
30x2 = offset is 60  => display records from 61-90

and so on...

Here is the code now:

```
offset = Time.now.wday-1*30
```